# python (pandas) merge within dataframe without for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

Hi I have the following dataframe:

```
>df1
    code    item01  item02  item03  item04  item05
0   1111    nan nan nan nan 440
1   1111    nan nan nan 650 nan
2   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
3   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
4   1111    32  nan nan nan nan
5   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
6   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
7   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
8   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
9   1111    nan nan nan nan nan
10  1111    nan nan nan nan nan
11  2222    20  nan nan nan nan
12  2222    nan nan nan nan nan
13  2222    nan nan nan 5   nan
14  2222    nan 7   nan nan nan
15  2222    nan nan nan nan nan
16  2222    nan nan nan nan nan
```

How can I merge using 'code' column within the dataframe to get df2 without for loop or iterrows().

```
>df2
    code    item01  item02  item03  item04  item05
0   1111    32  130 nan 650 440
1   2222    20  7   nan 5   nan
```

Comment: There is only one non nan value per group? If yes, `df.groupby('code').first()` shuld working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

If max one non value in column per group only:

```
df.groupby('code').first()
```

If possible multiple values - more general solution:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['code'])
df = df.groupby('code')[cols]
       .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: pd.Series(y.dropna().values)))
print (df)
        item01  item02  item03  item04  item05
code                                          
1111 0    32.0     NaN     NaN   650.0   440.0
2222 0    20.0     7.0     NaN     5.0     NaN
```

Comment: It did! Thanks, jezrael

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a groupby:

```
df1.groupby('code').max().reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Be careful, if there are many values for an item with the same code, here you will keep the biggest one.

The reset_index is only used to get Output DataFrame in the same format.